# Getting a Vertex by its Value

Tags: java, list, algorithm, graph, linked-list

I'm implementing a **Graph** in Java.

The `Graph` class uses a `LinkedList` for the *vertices*. And each *vertex* also contains a `LinkedList` of adjacent vertices.

I'm still working on my methods. I just need a quick clarification with a `getVertex()` method which accepts a `String` label and returns a `Vertex` that matches that label.

```
public class Graph
{
    private class Vertex
    {
        private String label;
        private LinkedList links; 
        private boolean visited; 
        
        Vertex(String label)
        {
            this.label = label; 
            LinkedList links = new LinkedList(); 
            visited = false; 
        }

        private void addEdge(Vertex vertex)
        {
            links.insertLast(vertex); 
        }

        private String getLabel()
        {
            return label; 
        }

        private LinkedList getAdjacent()
        {
            return links; 
        }

        private boolean isVisited()
        {
            return visited; 
        }

        private void visit()
        {
            visited = true; 
        }
 
        private void unvisit()
        {
            visited = false; 
        }
    }

    /* Classfields for Graph Class */   
    private LinkedList vertices; //Linked List for the vertices in the graph
    private int vCount; 
    private int eCount; 

    public Graph()
    { 
        LinkedList vertices = new LinkedList(); 
        vCount = 0; 
        eCount = 0; 
    } 

    public void addVertex(String label)
    {
        Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(label); 
        vertices.insertLast(newVertex);
        vCount++; 
    }

    public int getVertexCount()
    {
        return vCount; 
    }

    public Vertex getVertex(String label)
    {
        // what to return? 
    }
```

It should be very simple, but I can't understand how I'm going to import this label but return a `Vertex`, working with a `LinkedList`. Would appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on assignment on an assignment, and you are expected to use `LinkedList` that's fine, but it's the best choice of collection that serves as a storage of all vertices in the graph and also as the adjacency list of vertex

I suggest you addressing these issues:

- Firstly, don't use **row types** `LinkedList links`, you should always specify a generic type parameter `List<Vertex>`.
- Write your code against interfaces, not against implementations. I.e. use `List<Vertex>` instead of `LinkedList<Vertex>`. It makes your code more flexible.
- In order to be able to retrieve a particular *vertex* by *label*, you can use a `Map<String, Vertex>` to store all vertices of the graph. With that time complexity of the `getVertex()` will be reduced to constant time, it's way faster than iterate over the list. And the code is a single line `vertexByLabel.get(label)`.
- Maintaining a variable that hold a count of vertices is redundant because you can check the size of collection of vertices to get this value.
- `ArrayList` performs than `LinkedList` and has a better memory consumption. For that reason, it considered to be a general purpose implementation of the `List` interface and it's a preferred choice if you don't expect use cases like removal of elements by the means of `Iterator` while iterating over the list (which will be done in constant time, here `LinkedList` really shines). Also, `HashSet` might be useful in a role of the collection of *adjacencent vertices* because it will all you to ensure that there will be no duplicates.

So in regard to `getVertex()` method, if you'll agree with the suggestion to use map, the code will look like this:

```
private Map<String, Vertex> vertexByLabel = new HashMap<>(); // it is advisable to initialise collections, if you are not passing argument with collection that holds values to the constructor, but just assigning a new collection

public Vertex getVertex(String label) {
   return vertexByLabel.get(label);
}
```

I also advise you to make changes to the methods `addVertex()` and `addEdge()`. Firstly, I would rather expect to a method called `addVertex()` inside the `Vertex` class (we are adding a new vertex to the adjacency list of `this` vertex) and a method `addEdge()` inside the `Graph` (we are *connecting* vertices inside the graph).

And if order to connect the vertices method `addEdge()` of the graph will expect a vertex label as its first argument, and labes of the adjacent vertices as a [variable arity argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) (*varargs*).

---

In case if you have a strong requirement to utilize `LinkedLinked` exclusively and not allowed to use generic types. But frankly spiking, it doesn't seem a bright idea to disallow student to use generics. It doesn't reduce complexity a lot because instead you have to deal with manual down-casts, and it's a very bad practice.

Your method might look like this:

```
public Vertex getVertex(String label) {
    Vertex result = null;
    for (Object next: vertices) { // all elements in the collection of row type a treated by the compiler as being of type Object
        Vertex vertex = (Vertex) next; // you need to cast the element into the Vertex type in order to be able to access its field `label`
        if (vertex.label.equals(label)) {
            result = vertex;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. 

Yeah, we're specifically required to use a LinkedList and a LinkedList of Nodes for the graph. We also haven't covered generic types so we've just been using an Object LinkedList instead, similarly with Stacks and Queues. Same goes for the other methods you mentioned, we can't use anything not covered in the course content yet; so that would cover ArrayList, HashSet, Map.